# Even extension must have an element of even degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $E/F$ be a field extension of even degree. Is it true that there exists $a\in E-F$ such that $F(a):F$ is even?

I can see that if $v_1,\dots v_n$ is a basis for $E$, then $F(v_1,\dots,v_{i-r})(v_i)/ F(v_1,\dots, v_{i-r})$ is even for some $i,r$. This can be shown by extending $F$ by $v_i$'s one after another and adding those which don't lie in the previous algebraic span. But I fail to see the answer to the question at the top.

Comment: For what it's worth, if $F$ is of characteristic zero, or if $F$ is finite, then there exists $a$ in $E$ such that $E=F(a)$, and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_s$ be the separable closure of $F$ inside $E$. If $[F_s:F]$ is even, take $a$ to be a primitive element of $F_s/F$, see also the answer in the comment. Otherwise we have $[E:F_s]>1$ and $[E:F_s]$ is even. As $E/F_s$ is purely inseparable we get $[E:F_s]=2^k$ for some $k\geq1$. Now take any $b\in E\setminus F_s$. Again by the primitive element theorem there is some $c$ such that $F(c)=F(a,b)$ (note that for the primitive element theorem we only need one of the two generators to be separable). As $b$ has even degree over $F_s=F(a)$, $c$ has even degree over $F$.

Note that the same proof works if we replace 'even' with 'divisible by $p$' for some prime number $p$.